# Why does the following code not parse?

Tags: haskell

The following code does not parse:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ result
        where result = foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000]
    print $ result
        where result = last [1..1000000]
```

The compiler complains on the second print:
    src/Main.hs:10:5: parse error on input `print'

Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `where` clauses can be attached to bindings only, not to *expressions*.
In fact:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ result
        where result = foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000]
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ result
    where result = foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000]
```

i.e. the `where` defines local definitions for `main` not for the `print $ result` line.
Since `where` must be the last part of a binding obviously the following `print` expression causes a syntax error.

To use a `where` inside a `do`-block you have to use it when defining the `let` bindings such as this (very silly example):

```
main = do
    let result = f
        where f = foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000]
    print result
```

---

You can check this in the [grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5):

```
decl    →   gendecl
        |   (funlhs | pat) rhs

rhs     →   = exp [where decls]
        |   gdrhs [where decls]
```

Note that the `where decls` is part of the `rhs` rule which defines the right hand side of a declaration. If you check the rules for `exp` you wont find `where` mentioned:

```
exp     →   infixexp :: [context =>] type       (expression type signature)
        |   infixexp

infixexp    →   lexp qop infixexp               (infix operator application)
            |   - infixexp                      (prefix negation)
            |   lexp

lexp    →   \ apat1 … apatn -> exp              (lambda abstraction, n ≥ 1)
        |   let decls in exp                    (let expression)
        |   if exp [;] then exp [;] else exp    (conditional)
        |   case exp of { alts }                (case expression)
        |   do { stmts }                        (do expression)
        |   fexp
fexp    →   [fexp] aexp                         (function application)

aexp    →   qvar                                (variable)
        |   gcon                                (general constructor)
        |   literal
        |   ( exp )                             (parenthesized expression)
        |   ( exp1 , … , expk )                 (tuple, k ≥ 2)
        |   [ exp1 , … , expk ]                 (list, k ≥ 1)
        |   [ exp1 [, exp2] .. [exp3] ]         (arithmetic sequence)
        |   [ exp | qual1 , … , qualn ]         (list comprehension, n ≥ 1)
        |   ( infixexp qop )                    (left section)
        |   ( qop⟨-⟩ infixexp )                 (right section)
        |   qcon { fbind1 , … , fbindn }        (labeled construction, n ≥ 0)
        |   aexp⟨qcon⟩ { fbind1 , … , fbindn }  (labeled update, n  ≥  1)
```

Comment: Also, note that `let decls in exp` *is* mentioned, and can be used instead when you need it.